# Return an element in Pandas DataFrame with original data type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with one column as `int` and one column as `float`:

```
In [79]: data = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = np.arange(100), b = np.arange(100.1,200.0)))

In [80]: data.head()
Out[80]: 
   a      b
0  0  100.1
1  1  101.1
2  2  102.1
3  3  103.1
4  4  104.1
```

I want to return the 3rd row, column a as an integer.  I need the native python integer because it needs to be hashable.  I have tried the following and they don't work:

Gets casted to float because .iloc returns a series:

```
In [82]: data.iloc[3]['a']
Out[82]: 3.0 #
```

Returns a Series:

```
In [85]: d.iloc[[3]]['a']
Out[85]: 
3    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

This is what I want, but it's really ugly:

```
In [88]: int(d.iloc[[3]]['a'].values)
Out[88]: 3
```

Is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just convert the type using `astype`:

```
In [32]:

data.loc[3,'a'].astype(int)
Out[32]:
3
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you index the column first then the row you'll get what you want.

```
In [6]: data.iloc[3]['a']
Out[6]: 3.0

In [7]: data['a'].iloc[3]
Out[7]: 3
```